# How to debug segmentation fault of g++?

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault, aix

I tried to compile the code using g++4.4.6 on aix 6.1. I dont have gdb installed.
After compilation, It is showing Segmentation Fault error:-

```
../test/Corner.h: In member function 'void VirtualFlow<T>::vector_flow(typename T::Data**, typename T::Data**) [with T = NProcess<or_func<NetAndVal<ZVal2>, with_derivatives>, ConvexNoOverlapSize<16, 16, Multiply<65536l, AllPass<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal2> >, NoFlow<CornerT<NetAndVal<ZVal2> > > > > > >]':
../test/Corner.h:369: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

I tried to use -g option with to create .o file and looked for the problem.

```
opt/freeware/bin/g++ -g ConnectFlow2.C -o ConnectFlow2.o
```

but I was not able to debug.

Please share good practices of how to debug the segmentation fault.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the compiler crashing, not the program. You're gonna have to remove code until it fixes it, then figure out what's causing the bug. Updating GCC might fix it too.

Comment: 4.4.6 is the latest version in gcc4.4 series. I agree. Please share segmentation fault practices

Comment: We have decided to use 4.4.6 for now. Could anybody tell me which is the most stable version in gcc4.4 series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest upgrading your GCC compiler (since your old 4.4 compiler crashes). Try to get the GCC 4.6 [source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) then build it.

Don't forget to worry about dependencies, and to carefully read and follow the [installation instructions](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) (in particular, don't build in the source directory!).

If you really want to debug your compiler by yourself, rebuild it from source and recompile it with `-g`

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the code to leave the bare minimum for which the ICE still occurs and submit a bug report to GCC project. They have much higher chances of resolving it than you do.

Comment: But IIRC, 4.4.6 is the last release of GCC 4.4. They won't be any 4.4.7 probably. And GCC 4.6 is much different from 4.4!

Comment: Surely, they care about quality enough to issue a bugfix release from time to time?

Comment: The 4.4 series of GCC is quite old (started in 2009). Current GCC is **4.6** (and 4.7 should appear in spring 2012)! I remember having read that 4.4.6 is the last of the 4.4 series... (But you could pay some company to maintain your version, if you really cannot switch to GCC 4.6, which gives many improvements w.r.t. GCC 4.4 or 4.5).

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess, but it would worth trying to increase template depth with `-ftemplate-depth-103`. I don't know what is the default value, and how deep is your template-structure.